# Django admin file upload button not clickable - IN CHROME

Tags: javascript, python, django, file-upload, django-admin

[image]

UPDATE- It currently works in Safari but not chrome.

I was building an app and had the image upload section working previously, however, 2 weeks on in the project for some reason the upload file button in Django admin is no longer doing anything when clicked.

I can't work out what is blocking it as it's in the admin, Any suggestions?

This is for any of the apps in the project.
This is the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from desire import models


admin.site.register(models.Desire)

admin.site.register(models.RelatedProduct)
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from account.models import Account



class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email','username','date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin','is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email','username',)
    readonly_fields=('id', 'date_joined', 'last_login')

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()


admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # my APPs
    'personal',
    'account',
  
    

    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',


    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'bootstrap4',
    'fontawesome',
    'cropperjs',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account' # TODO: ADD THIS LINE.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend',
    'account.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend',

    )

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')

TEMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn/temp')

BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Desire model

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

# Create your models here.

def get_desire_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return 'desires/'

def get_default_desire_image():
    return "/desires/rope-play.webp"

def get_related_product_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return 'related-product/'

def get_default_related_product_image():
    return "related-product/swingerprofile.webp"


class Desire(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_desire_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_desire_image)
    related_products = models.ManyToManyField('RelatedProduct', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class RelatedProduct(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True,upload_to='related-product/', default="member/profile/02.jpg")
    # image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_related_product_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_related_product_image)
    redirect_url                = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True, unique=False, blank=True, help_text="The URL to be visited when a notification is clicked.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Account model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings
import os
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from model_utils import Choices

from friend.models import FriendList
from swinger.models import Swinger


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, couple_choice, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        couple_choice=couple_choice,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def get_profile_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return 'profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + '/profile_image.png'

def get_default_profile_image():
    return "profiles/swingerprofile.webp"


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    COUPLE_CHOICE = Choices('single', 'couple')

    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image           = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    hide_email              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    couple_choice           = models.CharField(choices=COUPLE_CHOICE, default='single', max_length=20)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        return str(self.profile_image)[str(self.profile_image).index('profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + "/"):]

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def user_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    FriendList.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def user_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Swinger.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

This is what is show in the source admin page.
I think it must be one of these scripts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Test | Change desire | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css">
  <script src="/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" defer></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css">


<script src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script src="/static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/responsive.css">
    

<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
</head>


<body class=" app-desire model-desire change-form"
  data-admin-utc-offset="0">

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">

    
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="branding">
        
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="/admin/">Django administration</a></h1>

        </div>
        
        
        <div id="user-tools">
            
                Welcome,
                <strong>wals**.com</strong>.
            
            
                
                    <a href="/">View site</a> /
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                <a href="/admin/password_change/">Change password</a> /
                
                <a href="/admin/logout/">Log out</a>
            
        </div>
        
        
        
    </div>
    <!-- END Header -->
    
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/admin/">Home</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="/admin/desire/">Desire</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="/admin/desire/desire/">Desires</a>
&rsaquo; Test
</div>

    

    <div class="main shifted" id="main">
      
        
          
<button class="sticky toggle-nav-sidebar" id="toggle-nav-sidebar" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
<nav class="sticky" id="nav-sidebar">
  


  
    <div class="app-account module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/account/" class="section" title="Models in the Account application">Account</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-account">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/account/account/">Accounts</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/account/account/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-auth module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/auth/" class="section" title="Models in the Authentication and Authorization application">Authentication and Authorization</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-group">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/auth/group/">Groups</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/auth/group/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-chat module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/chat/" class="section" title="Models in the Chat application">Chat</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-privatechatroom">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/chat/privatechatroom/">Private chat rooms</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/chat/privatechatroom/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-roomchatmessage">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/chat/roomchatmessage/">Room chat messages</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/chat/roomchatmessage/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-unreadchatroommessages">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/chat/unreadchatroommessages/">Unread chat room messagess</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/chat/unreadchatroommessages/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-desire module current-app">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/desire/" class="section" title="Models in the Desire application">Desire</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-desire current-model">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/desire/desire/" aria-current="page">Desires</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/desire/desire/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-relatedproduct">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/desire/relatedproduct/">Related products</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/desire/relatedproduct/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-friend module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/friend/" class="section" title="Models in the Friend application">Friend</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-friendlist">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/friend/friendlist/">Friend lists</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/friend/friendlist/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-friendrequest">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/friend/friendrequest/">Friend requests</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/friend/friendrequest/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-notification module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/notification/" class="section" title="Models in the Notification application">Notification</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-notification">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/notification/notification/">Notifications</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/notification/notification/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-public_chat module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/public_chat/" class="section" title="Models in the Public_Chat application">Public_Chat</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-publicchatroom">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/public_chat/publicchatroom/">Public chat rooms</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/public_chat/publicchatroom/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-publicroomchatmessage">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/public_chat/publicroomchatmessage/">Public room chat messages</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/public_chat/publicroomchatmessage/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-swinger module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/swinger/" class="section" title="Models in the Swinger application">Swinger</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-swinger">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/swinger/swinger/">Swingers</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/swinger/swinger/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  


</nav>

        
      
      <div class="content">
        
          
        
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content" class="colM">
          
          <h1>Change desire</h1>
          <h2>Test</h2>
          <div id="content-main">


  <ul class="object-tools">
    
      

<li>
    
    <a href="/admin/desire/desire/1/history/" class="historylink">History</a>
</li>



    
  </ul>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="desire_form" novalidate><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="juad4Png7eSuXsum6nCzutBDYsXfvxzVpfcJfwAOnm5LY6WyQMQgf3JyKsFwOKPE">
<div>







  <fieldset class="module aligned ">
    
    
    
        <div class="form-row field-title">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label class="required" for="id_title">Title:</label>
                        
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="Test" class="vTextField" maxlength="200" required id="id_title">
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-description">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_description">Description:</label>
                        
                            <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="10" class="vLargeTextField" id="id_description">
test desription</textarea>
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-content">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_content">Content:</label>
                        
                            <textarea class="vLargeTextField tinymce" cols="40" data-mce-conf="{&quot;theme&quot;: &quot;silver&quot;, &quot;height&quot;: 500, &quot;menubar&quot;: false, &quot;plugins&quot;: &quot;advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,paste,code,help,wordcount&quot;, &quot;toolbar&quot;: &quot;undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help&quot;, &quot;spellchecker_languages&quot;: &quot;Afrikaans=af,Arabic / Algerian Arabic=ar,Asturian=as,Azerbaijani=az,Bulgarian=bg,Belarusian=be,Bengali=bn,Breton=br,Bosnian=bs,Catalan=ca,Czech=cs,Welsh=cy,Danish=da,German=de,Lower Sorbian=ds,Greek=el,+English / Australian English / British English=en,Esperanto=eo,Spanish / Argentinian Spanish / Colombian Spanish / Mexican Spanish / Nicaraguan Spanish / Venezuelan Spanish=es,Estonian=et,Basque=eu,Persian=fa,Finnish=fi,French=fr,Frisian=fy,Irish=ga,Scottish Gaelic=gd,Galician=gl,Hebrew=he,Hindi=hi,Croatian=hr,Upper Sorbian=hs,Hungarian=hu,Armenian=hy,Interlingua=ia,Indonesian=id,Igbo=ig,Ido=io,Icelandic=is,Italian=it,Japanese=ja,Georgian / Kabyle=ka,Kazakh=kk,Khmer=km,Kannada=kn,Korean=ko,Kyrgyz=ky,Luxembourgish=lb,Lithuanian=lt,Latvian=lv,Macedonian=mk,Malayalam=ml,Mongolian=mn,Marathi=mr,Burmese=my,Norwegian Bokm\u00e5l=nb,Nepali=ne,Dutch=nl,Norwegian Nynorsk=nn,Ossetic=os,Punjabi=pa,Polish=pl,Portuguese / Brazilian Portuguese=pt,Romanian=ro,Russian=ru,Slovak=sk,Slovenian=sl,Albanian=sq,Serbian / Serbian Latin=sr,Swedish=sv,Swahili=sw,Tamil=ta,Telugu=te,Tajik=tg,Thai=th,Turkmen=tk,Turkish=tr,Tatar=tt,Udmurt=ud,Ukrainian=uk,Urdu=ur,Uzbek=uz,Vietnamese=vi,Simplified Chinese / Traditional Chinese=zh&quot;, &quot;directionality&quot;: &quot;ltr&quot;, &quot;mode&quot;: &quot;exact&quot;, &quot;strict_loading_mode&quot;: 1, &quot;elements&quot;: &quot;id_content&quot;}" id="id_content" name="content" rows="10"></textarea>
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-image">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_image">Image:</label>
                        
                            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="id_image"><input type="hidden" name="initial-image" id="initial-id_image">
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-image2">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_image2">Image2:</label>
                        
                            <input type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" id="id_image2">
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-related_products">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_related_products">Related products:</label>
                        
                            <div class="related-widget-wrapper">
    <select name="related_products" id="id_related_products" multiple>
  <option value="2" selected>Giant Lollipop</option>

</select>
    
        <a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-related" id="add_id_related_products"
            href="/admin/desire/relatedproduct/add/?_to_field=id&amp;_popup=1"
            title="Add another related product"><img src="/static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg" alt="Add"></a>
    
</div>
                        
                    
                    
                        <div class="help">Hold down “Control”, or “Command” on a Mac, to select more than one.</div>
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
</fieldset>













<div class="submit-row">

<input type="submit" value="Save" class="default" name="_save">

    
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="/admin/desire/desire/1/delete/" class="deletelink">Delete</a></p>


<input type="submit" value="Save and add another" name="_addanother">
<input type="submit" value="Save and continue editing" name="_continue">


</div>



    <script id="django-admin-form-add-constants"
            src="/static/admin/js/change_form.js"
            
            async>
    </script>




<script id="django-admin-prepopulated-fields-constants"
        src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js"
        data-prepopulated-fields="[]">
</script>


</div>
</form></div>

          
          <br class="clear">
        </div>
        <!-- END Content -->
        <div id="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide models.py file

Comment: I have uploaded the model to the bottom.

Comment: Is desire your appname because you import like from desire import models?

Comment: No UltimateDesires is the main app, then desire is an app inside.

Answer (score 0):

just remove self and filename from function.

instead:

```
def get_desire_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return 'desires/'
```

try this:

```
def get_desire_image_filepath(instance, filename):
    return 'desires/'.format(instance.user.id, filename) #user.id is depends on your view
```

Comment: I tried this but still the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. the button still won't do anything on clicking. 
Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score -1):

So after a whole day trying multiple things, it turns out I needed to update chrome!

Comment: Actually, this solves the issue for me. I can't explain why